# Array index out of range error on conditional declaration Swift

Tags: ios, swift, conditional-statements, declaration

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if let getimURL = newslists[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageURL as String?{

        if getimURL != "None"{
            return 230.0
        };  return 70.0


    }else{
        return 70.0
    }
}
```

The error appears often when I have bad connection, possibly causing the `newslists` array to populate too slowly,

Anyway, the index out of bounds error refers to the line

`if let getimURL = newslists[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageURL as String?{`

My question is, if there is an issue with this line shouldn't the program run the code in between the `else` brackets?

Is this not the purpose of the conditional declaration?

If not, how would I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `if let` declaration is to unwrap the `String?` optional. The error is when accessing the array you assume `newslists[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` exists instead of checking it. Try something like

```
if newslists.count > indexPath.section {
   if newslists[indexPath.section].count > indexPath.row {
      if let getimURL = newslists[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageURL as? String {
          if getimURL != "None"{
             return 230.0 
          }
      }
   }
} 
return 70.0
```

Also you are correct about the bad connection being a problem. If that is your data source and it is dependent on information relying on a network request (which is performed on a background thread) there is no guarantee that the data source will be populated when this method is called.

Comment: This fixed it, not sure why I needed this in the first place. Is it a common problem do you know?

Comment: I would not really consider it a "problem". Pretty much the reason we check `newslists.count` is because you can not access an array at an index that doesn't exist. If you have an array with 1 element and you try to access array[5] you will get the same error. Your issue was you have an empty array because your app had not yet fetched the data when this data source method is being called so you just have to check to make sure an item does exist at that index in the data source before attempting to access it.

Comment: So yeah this is a common thing to consider when using background operations to populate data sources. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That *is* the point of the conditional declaration, but that's *not* how array indexing is done in Swift. However, adding your own functionality there is pretty easy:

```
extension CollectionType where Index : ForwardIndexType, Index : Comparable {
  subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
    return indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
  }
}

let jo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

jo[safe: 2] // 3?
```

(which I got from [here](http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/24/dear-erica-extend-safe-index/))

Problem here is that you'll have a double optional now. To solve that, you'll need optional chaining:

```
if let getimURL = newslists[safe: indexPath.section]?[safe: indexPath.row]?.imageURL.flatMap({ $0 as? String }) {
```

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your implementations of the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` delegate methods aren't reporting the correct length. That will cause the table view to provide an index path that's out of bounds of your array. You should probably be returning `newslists[section].length` for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `newslists.length` for `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning 70 no matter what?

```
if getimURL != "None"{
        return 230.0
    };  return 70.0 //Right here!!


}else{
    return 70.0
}
```

Shouldn't it be...?

```
if getimURL != "None"{
    return 230.0
}else{
    return 70.0
}
```